# Saving mySQL file with DATE using cmd

Tags: php, mysql, linux, cmd, window

I am trying to save mysql backups to a folder with the date included in the filename. I can save the files fine without including %date% but when I add it and run it returns
"Errcode:2 - No such file or directory"

the cmd line i have is:

```
mysqldump -uroot -p[password] --result-file="C:\Users\.....\DatabaseDumps\TestBackup_%date%.sql" Minerva
```

I have removed the password and save path

I cannot find anything online that shows a solution to this so any advice would be great. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Linux**
For linux I've done this in the past with backticks (I think that's what they're called) check this bash script I just made

```
echo "this is text" > file-`date +"%m_%d_%Y"`.text
```

This creates the file  file-02_26_2015.txt with content "this is text"

**Windows**
See the accepted solution here. Effectively you are dumping the output of %DATE% into another variable and then calling that

https://superuser.com/questions/47885/windows-command-line-create-a-file-with-the-current-date-in-its-name

Comment: Thank you this really helped. Turns out just having %DATE% in the line returns 27/02/15 and the when it runs it doesnt like the '/' so my new line is TestBackup_%date:~0,2%_%date:~3,2%_%date:~6,4%___%Time:~0,2%%Time:~3,2%.sql